# Signed bytes and encodedSignature explanation?

Tags: operation

Im haven't been able to find an explanation of these to parameters that several libraries use when signing the operation:

```
SignedBytes = forgedOpGroup.ToString() + "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
EncodedSignature = "edsigtXomBKi5CTRf5cjATJWSyaRvhfYNHqSUGrn4SdbYRcGwQrUGjzEfQDTuqHhuA8b2d8NarZjz8TRf65WkpQmo423BtomS8Q"
```

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature in hex is the last 64 bytes (128 hex characters). `edsigtXomBKi5CTRf5cjATJWSyaRvhfYNHqSUGrn4SdbYRcGwQrUGjzEfQDTuqHhuA8b2d8NarZjz8TRf65WkpQmo423BtomS8Q` is the signature of 64 zero bytes, also referred to as the zero signature.

This can be used when you don't need to validate the signature (for example simulating operations) as well as anonymous operations (seed_nonce_revelation, double_endorsement_evidence, double_baking_evidence and activate_account operations).

Answer (score 1):

That's just a dummy signature and not a real one. Could be used for the activation operation or when simulating an operation in the node (e.g. in order to determine what gas/storage limit to use).